# Is it possible to use an Android phone in "disk mode"?

Tags: sd-card, files, disk-drive

If I connect an iPhone to a PC it is not possible to copy files between the PC and the iPhone. I would like to be able to do this because it would be useful.

What happens if I connect an Android phone to a PC? Do I see it as a disk or is it similar to the iPhone?

Comment: Wait, hang on! Why are you asking about iPhone in not being able to copy files? Use iTunes for that!

Answer (score 13):

Absolutely, and it's very easy.  This is the procedure for my Samsung Galaxy S; other phones may be different:

1. Plug in the USB cable and a USB icon
   appears in the notification area at
   the top of the screen.
2. Pull down the
   notification and tap "USB
   connected".
3. Tap "Mount" on the
   dialog box that's displayed.
4. Two
   removable drives show up on my PC;
   one for the built-in flash memory,
   and one for the expansion SD card.

Comment: great. It is what i hoped; soon or later i will try to get an Android phone :-) Thank you !!

Comment: Yeah, this varies by phone (or possibly carrier?) - on the Moto Droid, you only see the expansion SD card, not the built-in memory.

Comment: This works fine, but I've found that I get better data transfer rates if I remove the SD card and use a card reader.

Comment: power users can push things to sd card w/o mounting in in terminal type adb push <file on desk> /sdcard/

Comment: Only one little thing, there are Android phones that have this function disabled, like for example the Samsung Galaxy S that requires to install a special app on your computer to copy files from/to the phone.

Comment: @doliveras: I have a Galaxy S and don't need any app (I presume you mean Kies?) to copy files.  If yours is set up that way (mine wasn't when I got the phone), you can change it in _Settings > Applications > USB settings_: you get a choice of Kies, Media player, Mass storage or Ask on connection.  Select one of the last two.

Answer (score 2):

On my HTC Desire you choose "Disk drive" mode although you only see the SDCard not the internal memory.

Comment: Same thing for HTC Hero. I imagine all HTC phones can do this.